# How to create models depending on different users in Django?

Tags: python, django, database

I'm going to create a model called student. But the model
might be a little different due to different users: trial
and expert users. Expert users might have an additional field
to store comments.

```
class Student(models.Model):
     id = models.CharField( max_length=7,primary_key=True)
     name = models.CharField(_('name'),max_length=8, default=""); 
     address = models.CharField(_('address'),max_length=30,blank=True,default="")    
     # comments field is not available for trial users
     # and for expert users the max_length should also a variable
     # rather than a constant
     # the switch
     if(settings.version !="trial"):
         comments = models.CharField(_("comments"),max_length=30);
```

My idea is to store an attribute to store the user's versions. And
when it comes to initialize the model, the switch will determine
if the field will be applied or not.
But

1. Where should I store the attibute? Is it appropriate to be inside
   settings.py? Or it should be an attribute of a customer?
2. If it's not appropriate. Should I create different models for different versions?
3. Do the tables should be created for different models with only one or
   two fields different?

Answer (score 0):

You can create only one model for it. There is no need another model.

If you want to some sections available on models, you can create a function with using if else at your views.py.

For filter user type, you must define user type in your model first.

If user is trial user you will not call this fields with forms. That's why trial user's fields will be null or blank. If user not trial user all fields will be available. You can do it this in your view.py and template sections with forms and if else commands or using filter fuctions.

I think this is easy way for you.

Second way you can create a second user model for expert users.